# LWC audio tag issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, audio

I'm trying to play audio files with  tag, but for some reason, controls are grayed-out.

[image: Imgur]

Here is the code:

```
<audio controls src={url}></audio>
```

I tried googling it, but there seemed to be no audio issue related questions in StackExchange. I checked in playground and it works there.

Comment: It depends on where the audio file is coming from. By default, the file would need to be in your org (e.g. a static resource file).

Comment: Ensuring your URL is pointing to your domain (as in static resource) is first step here.Browser blocks any URL not whitelisted in CSP/CORS.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have audio recordings that are done by third-party service, host address is white-listed in Remote Site Settings

Comment: @ytiq Remote Site Settings won't be enough, you need to use the CSP settings to allow access to third-party resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sfdcfofx for suggestion, was missing CSP settings plus needed to update attribute

```
<audio controls="controls" src={url}></audio>
```